# Why I receive Out of system resources when a thread invokes asynchron this method 

Tags: multithreading, delphi, asynchronous, bitmap

I have a TThread, and it invokes the next function:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure TfrImageShow.Load(bmBitmap:TBitmap);
begin

   self.bmBitmapCopy.Width:=bmBitmap.Width;
   self.bmBitmapCopy.Height:=bmBitmap.Height;
   self.bmBitmapCopy.Canvas.Draw(0,0,bmBitmap);
end;
```

And my thread in Execution invokes this method, and after a time it gives an error: Out of system resources? Why because Bitmap is not a VCL component. It also use Critical Section

```
TThread.execute
begin
 ....
   csCriticalSection.Enter;
       frImage.Load(bmBitmap);
   csCriticalSection.Leave;
....
end;
```

Also I have a question if that Critical Section is usefull(i mention you that there isn't any other thread), only sometimes Application Thread read bmBitmapCopy from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protecting the access to the GUI (main thread VCL) from a thread with a `critical secion` is not the right way to handle this.

Since the VCL is not directly accessible from other threads, the thread must synchronize the call to to the VCL.

example (if your Delphi version supports `anonymous methods`):

```
Synchronize(
  procedure
    begin
      frImage.Load(bmBitmap);
    end);
```

The `Synchronize` method will swap to the main thread during execution.

If you have a older Delphi version, add a method to your `TThread` class and call Load from there:

```
TThread.CallLoad;
begin
  frImage.Load(bmBitmap);
end;

TThread.Execute;
begin
  ...
  Synchronize( Self.CallLoad);
  ...
end;
```

The use of a `critical section` is to serialize the access from two (or more) threads to a common object/variable etc. But in this case calls to the VCL resources from a thread is strictly forbidden.

Comment: Synchronize only takes parameterless methods.

Comment: @NGLN, updated the answer with an example using anonymous methods to solve the parameter call. Thanks.

Comment: @NGLN, and also another example using a thread method for synchronizing with parameters.